# Is there a better way to call a .env file exists check function in cypress?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I would like to check if there is a `.env` file exists in the root folder before running the test. I have added below function in the index.js but it is not checking if the file exists. Could someone please advise the issue here ?

cypress/ plugins/ `index.js`

```
const  filePath = "../../../.env";

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('file:preprocessor', cucumber()),
      on('before:browser:launch', (browser, launchOptions) => {
        console.log("Print browser name: "+browser.name);
        fileCheck(filePath);  // calling the function here
    
      });
};


function fileCheck(filePath) => {
        try {
            if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
                console.log("Awesome ! .env file exists in the root directory ! ");
            }
        } catch(err) {
            console.error(err)
            console.log("Oh !, .env file is missing, please add !");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried moving your error handling into the if/else block? `fs.existsSync()` returns a Boolean, so even if the file is not found, it would be `false` and not an exception. Looking at your code, I think that if the file were not found right now, and no exception is thrown, then your code would appear to "do nothing".

Comment: @agoff Will try moving the error condition in the else condition. let me try that

Comment: @agoff I have tried, but this is not working again..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's enough to check it in a before action, then you can do:

```
before(() => {
cy.on('fail', (error) => {
  error.message = 'Oh !, .env file is missing, please add !';
  throw error;
})
cy.readFile('.env', {timeout: 50}).should('exist');
```

});

Comment: Thank you, the before action should be mentioned inside the test file right. But I need something to add in `cypress/ plugins/ index.js ` file as I would like to check before running the test file

Comment: This is great! I see no need to make extra complication with a task. BTW `cy.once(...)` is another option that limits the error catching to just the `cy.readFile()`. Also `cy.off('fail', (error) => {...` after the read.